# Explicit transition matrix

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

An urn $U$ contains always $N$ balls, some white and some black balls. Fix $p \in ]0,1[$; at each stage a coin having probability $p$ of landing heads is flipped. If heads appear, then a ball is chosen at random from the urn and is replaced by a white ball; if tails appear, then a ball is chosen at random from the urn and is replaced by a black ball. For any $n \geq 0$ let $X_n$ denote the number of white balls in the urn after the $n^{th}$ stage.

It's easy to see that $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a Markov chain on $\left\{ 0,...,N\right\}$ . How to explicit its transition matrix $Q$. Help me please. Thank you so much.

Definition of a transition matrix:

[image]

Comment: I'm using the firefox addon Request Policy which by default is blocking access from SO to imgur, where that image of the definition is located. The thing is that for some reason this time it didn't even show a placeholder for the image and I saw it only now. It's confusing that you put half of the content as an image. It's also bad that you aren't consistent with the notation yourself: You call the transition matrix $Q$ and this pic calls it $P$. Well, I stuck to your notation before you added the picture.

Comment: The only important thing to remember, though, is the relation between the set of new probabilities and the old ones, and that is what I state in my first paragraph. Some times you may see people defining ${\hat {\bf p}}$ as a row vector instead. Then the transition matrix acts as ${\hat {\bf p}}_{n+1}={\hat {\bf p}}_n{\hat Q}$, and its normalization is by row, not by column as I wrote. This is because the transition matrix in such  a case is slightly different than with the prescription I wrote. The relation between both is ${\hat Q}=Q^T$. Of course, it also is ${\hat {\bf p}}={\bf p}^T$.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the state vector as the column vector ${\bf p}=(p_0,\cdots,p_N)^T$ of probabilities $p_i$ of the urn being in state $i$, i.e., of there being $i$ white balls in the urn. At each stage, the transition matrix $Q$ brings each state ${\bf p}_n$ to the new state ${\bf p}_{n+1}$ by operating as ${\bf p}_{n+1}=Q{\bf p}_n$

Say after a given stage $n$ there are $i$ white ball. The probability of taking then a white ball is $p_w=i/N$. Thus, in the following stage the probability of

1. Increasing the number of white balls by $1$ is $(1-p_w)p$
2. Keeping the same number of white balls is $p_wp+(1-p_w)(1-p)$
3. Decreasing the number of white balls by  $1$ is $p_w(1-p)$

Thus the transition matrix $Q$ is given by
$$Q_{ij}\,=\,(1-p_w)p\,\delta_{i(j+1)}\,+\,p_w(1-p)\,\delta_{i(j-1)}\,+\,(p_wp+(1-p_w)(1-p))\,\delta_{ij}$$

That is, at each column $j$ of $Q$ the only non-zero values are the diagonal terms and one above/below them.

We can check that this is indeed a transition matrix as $$\sum_jQ_{ij}=(1-p_w)p+p_w(1-p)+p_wp+(1-p_w)(1-p)=1$$
as it should.

Comment: Why is the probability of taking then a white ball  $p_w=i/N$?

Comment: State $i\in[0,\cdots,N]$, as you mentioned, means there are $i$ white balls.

Comment: I notice now the misunderstanding: your ${\bf X}$ being in boldface I took it as a vector, but I think now you just meant the integer value of white balls, i.e, the same as my $i$.

Comment: I removed the reference to ${\bf X}$. Is this clearer now?

Comment: Why is the probability of increasing the number of white balls by one $(1-p_w)p$? Why it has $(1-p_w)$?

Comment: At each stage you are 1) taking at random a ball and then 2) tossing the coin. **IF** the ball in 1) was black **and** you got heads in 2), **then** you are actually exchanging a black ball by a white ball. Hence the number of white balls in the urn increases by $1$. **What is the chance of this happening?** This is a compound event of 1) getting a black ball at random **and** 2) getting heads, both events independent of each other. The prob. of 1) is 1 - the prob of getting a white ball, i.e. $(1-p_w)$; that of 2) is simply $p$, by definition of $p$, and the total prob is the product of both.